# Method to Solve a System of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a, b, x, y \in Q$.
Find $x$ and $y$ given that:

1) $a$ and $b$ cannot both be zero
2) $ax - by = 1$
3) $ay + bx = 0$

Assuming $a \ne 0$,
$\quad$from (3), we get $y=-\frac{bx}{a}$
$\quad$and then substituting into (2) and solving we get: $x=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$ and $y=-\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}$

Similarly, assuming $b \ne 0$, we get $x=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$ and $y=-\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}$

So, we have the same solution in both cases.
Is there is some other way to solve it without trying the 2 cases?

Comment: Well you don't need to assume anything till the step of dividing by $a^2+b^2$, which is given to be non-zero.

Comment: i have the same solution as you

Comment: @Macavity I've edited the question to provide the intermediate step where assuming $a \ne 0$ we get $y=-\frac{bx}{a}$. So, I had to assume $a \ne 0$ in the intermediate step.

Comment: @user137481  Multiply (2) with $a$, (3) with $b$ and add. Now all you need is $a^2+b^2\ne 0$ to get the result for $x$. If you do it the other way round and subtract, you get $y$. No multiple cases.

Comment: @Macavity Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could say that $A = \begin{bmatrix}a &-b\\b & a\end{bmatrix}$ is non-singular

$A\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
\mathbf x = A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac a{a^2+b^2}\\-\frac {b}{a^2+b^2}\end{bmatrix}$